# How to print several values in row on any position of screen in C

Tags: c, printf

For example I print next using `printf`:

```
printf("%-30s %-30s %-30s %30s\n", "Title", "Name", "ID", "Position");
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
{    
   printf("%97s\n", position);
}

Title    Name     ID     Position
                         a123
                         b123
                         c123
                         d123
                         e123
```

How can I print next?

```
Title    Name     ID     Position
                         a123 b123 c123
                         d123 e123
```

Comment: What? How did you print the first one?

Comment: ***Show Code***

Comment: Use nested loops. The outer loop is for the rows, the inner loop is for the positions on the same row.

Comment: I have added code, this is very simple code. I do can print values each new line, but I wish to print all values in row

Comment: Print the 93 spaces at the beginning before the inner loop.

Comment: Barmar, thanks for your reply, so inner loop will new position each time?

Comment: @FelX3 We need you to show the code that tries to do what you want, not the old code.

Comment: @Barmar, ,thanks, I did manage to solve it with your help, just printed before the position that I desire

Comment: @chux, it typo mistake, thanks